# .NET Core and Razor cannot load image in img src 404

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor

I have application written in .NET Core and View in Razor.
This is standard `Login.cshtml` view generated from Visual Studio Identity.
In this view I want to include img:

```
<img src="../../../../Assets/0rdfEnHw.jpeg" alt="">
```

Image is added in folder:

```
MyApp:
-Areas
  -Identity
    -Pages
      -Account
       -Login.cshtml
-Assets
  -0rdfEnHw.jpeg
```

And in browser I have error:

```
GET https://localhost:5001/Assets/0rdfEnHw.jpeg 404
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the Static files are stored within the project's web root directory. The default directory is `{content root}/wwwroot`.

To serve files outside of web root (like your scenario: using the Assets folder), you could configuring the Static File Middleware as follows:

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Assets")),
            RequestPath = "/Assets"
        });
```

Then, the view page as below:

```
 <img src="~/Assets/Image2.jpg" />
```

[Note] By using the above method, since it changes the default static file location, it might cause the CSS files and JQuery file not load success (because, they are using the `wwwroot` folder as the default folder, you have to change the path for them),

So, I suggest you change the Assets folder location, try to drag it into the wwwroot folder, like this:

[image]

Then, using the following code to load image.

```
 <img src="~/Assets/Image2.jpg" />
```

By using this method, there is no need to change the Static File Middleware, just using the default setting:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

More detail information about the Static files in ASP.NET Core, please check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path like this,

```
<img src="~/Assets/0rdfEnHw.jpeg" />
```

And Make Sure your assets folder is under wwwroot folder, as static content in Asp.Net Core is served under this.